# How to know if a syscall returned an error?

Tags: c, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I try to reproduce `strace` behaviour in C, using `ptrace`.

I would like to check if a syscall returned an error (and what error<sup>1</sup>), but I don't know how to do this?

Here is an example of an output of `strace` I try to reproduce:

```
execve("./exit", ["./exit"], 0x7ffff059f250 /* 62 vars */) = 0
read(42, NULL, 0)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I tried to compare the return value of the syscall<sup>2</sup> with -1, but they aren't equal.

I see in [GLIBC](https://sourceware.org/glibc/) syscall's implementation (`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syscall.c`) that `INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERROR_P` macro is used, which seems to be a macro for internal use of [GLIBC](https://sourceware.org/glibc/). I found two implementations of this macro:

- First one, in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sysdep.h`:

```c
#define INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERROR_P(val) ((unsigned long int)(val) > -4096UL)
```

- Second one, in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/x32/times.c`:

```c
#define INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERROR_P(val) ((unsigned long long int)(val) >= -4095LL)
```

Since the first one is in a header directly related to the system (unlike the second one), I would tend to say that this is the one used by `syscall`. But I don't know if they are generics and so if I can use it.

<sup>1</sup>To recover the errno code, inverting the syscall return value (`-rax`) seems to work.

<sup>2</sup>With `ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, ...)`, we can get the child registers, and store them in a `struct user_regs_struct` (defined in `sys/user.h`). Accessing the `rax` member of this structure, we have the return value of the syscall.

Comment: On a syscall error (under x86), IIRC, it sets the carry flag.

Comment: What does “I tried to compare the return value of the syscall with -1” mean? **You** cannot compare the return value of `syscall` to anything until it is made visible to you somehow. Do you mean you tried to trace a program, and in that program you had code to compare the return value of the call to −1? Do you mean you looked at the strace output and looked for “-1” in it? Something else?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The return value of a syscall is stored in the register `rax`. I mean I compared it with -1. Effectively, I have a program which traces another with `ptrace`. I'm not sure I understood your question, did I answer it correctly?

Comment: So the actual problem is you have a program attempting to use `ptrace`, and that program is not behaving the way you expect. For that, you should provide a [mre] of the program in the question. I see you have already entered an answer, and it supports this: You apparently were getting a correct value returned in the `rax` member of a structure but were not interpreting it as needed. Providing a [mre] would have allowed other people to reproduce and diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

`syscall` doesn't seem to set the carry flag.
Otherwise, like we can see on [this `syscall` manual](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Elangley/CNT5605/2017-Summer/assembly-example/assembly.html), if `rax` is negative (lower than 0), it indicates an error.
Since `rax` in `struct user_regs_struct` is unsigned, we just have to cast it in signed, and we can know if syscall returned and error, and what error (`-rax` to get errno code).

```c
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    // strace logic ...
    if ((long long)regs.rax < 0)
        printf(" = -1 %s (%s)\n", strerrorname_np((int)-regs.rax), strerror((int)-regs.rax));
    else
        printf(" = %llu\n", regs.rax);
    // ...
}
```